# Twilio inbound messages - Not Shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sms, twilio

I'm having a problem receiving Messages and i don't know where and what goes wrong.

Right now i received messages from the United States that are shown in the Inbound Twilio Dashboard and are accessible through the API.

e.g.:

```
<% @client.account.sms.messages.list({ from: "#{@contact.mobile}", }).each do |message| %>
```

Bur **responses from other countries** don't show up anywhere.

For Sending and receiving messages i use the format:

```
+1757*******
```

Has the format something to do with it ? What am i missing?

From Twilio Doc:

> Phone numbers should be formatted with a '+' and country code e.g.,
>   +16175551212 (E.164 format). For 'to' numbers without a '+', Twilio will use the same country code as the 'from' number. Twilio will also
>   attempt to handle locally formatted numbers for that country code
>   (e.g. (415) 555-1212 for US, 07400123456 for GB). If you are sending
>   to a different country than the 'from' number, you must include a '+'
>   and the country code to ensure proper delivery.

**After some serious Twilio Scanning i found the Answer - Read below**

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  Not sure I totally understand your question.  Are you saying that you are trying to send SMS messages to non-US numbers and they are not going through, and not showing up in your Messages Log?

Comment: Hey Devin, Sending works just fine. Receiving is the problem. I don't know what I'm missing, but i can't receive messages from other countries than the US. They don't even show up in the Logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone with the Same Issue.

When Setting up a Twilio account you receive a US Number, which works a little different from other Countries.

[SMS Enabled Phone Numbers](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/phone-numbers/which-countries-does-twilio-have-phone-numbers-in-and-what-are-their-capabilities#sms-enabled-phone-numbers): Some are able to send SMS internationally and domestically, but others are only able to send and receive SMS domestically.

For the United States there is no Mobile, only Toll-Free and Local. With that, other carriers (Outside the US) wont even let your sms trough, thinking that the number on the other end is not a Mobile.

Basically, **only US Numbers can send an SMS `to` a US Number, other countries can't.**

So i bought a UK Number and everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Evangelist here.

This could be a number of things. So first off, do the incoming messages show in your [Message Logs](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/messages) on the Twilio Dashboard?

If they don't show up, then you make sure you have a URL set for number receiving them.

If they do show up, copy one of the numbers as shown in the logs and try this out in your app. It's a little tricky to be specific without more details, but I expect you should use the `+<country><number>` format as stated. So for US: +1415xxxx..., for the UK +447590xxxx...' and so on.

You could also try running this code:

```
 <% @client.account.messages.list({to: your_twilio_number}).each do |message| %>
```

Display all the messages and check for the inbound messages there, then try again once you've double checked your `contact.mobile` formatting.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Would you mind joining me in Chat? => http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57155/twilio-receiving-sms